# How should array query parameters be handled when a single value is expected?

Tags: openapi

I'm building an API, and I'm referencing OpenAPI for certain standards and best practices.

Let's say I have a paginated endpoint, `/users`. `/users` handles pagination using query parameters, `offset` and `limit`.

So if I want the first 50 users from my API, I would call `GET /users?offset=0&limit=50`.

Implementing this is very straight forward, but what if an API consumer calls the following:

```
/users?offset=0&offset=20&limit=50&limit100`
```

How should an API handle multiple values when only one value is expected for each query parameter? Should I throw an error? Should I only accept the first value for each parameter?

Is there anything in the latest OpenAPI spec that covers how this should be handled?

Comment: Consider also asking this in the OpenAPI Specification repository: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/discussions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OpenAPI definition, if a query parameter allows multiple values, its schema should be defined as `array`:

```yaml
  parameters:
    - name: q
      in: query
      schema:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
```

When the schema of the parameter is single value, it's considered a violation of the schema for the client to send multiple values. But it is out of the scope of OpenAPI whether the server will tolerate this error.

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: offset
    in: query
    schema:
      type:  integer
  - name: limit
    in: query
    schema:
      type:  integer
```

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, When you have multiple values with the same keys, it returns an array of values like this:

```
{ offset: [ '0', '20' ], limit: [ '50', '100' ] }
```

It is available on the request object on query i.e `request.query`. It might create a range for offset and limit just speculating.

It could be the range for offset from 0-20 and the limit can be 50-100. The algorithm in open API must be able to handle it.

A better place should be to ask in an open API Q&A.